# entering files path using input()

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract information from excel file, and eventually put the values from the excel in a docx file. when I wrote the code I entered a specific path using the syntax (r"file path), and I had no problem. because the program was created for a friend of mine, and it will run on a different computer, I am looking for a way for my friend to open the exact excel file he wanted. down below you can see some codes. thanks in advance to anybody that spend some time trying to solve it!

this one worked for me:

```
loc = (r"C:\Users\dddor\Desktop\python24\report_example.xlsx")
```

this one brings error:

```
loc=(input('enter file location: '))
```

I also tried, but same error poped:

```
loc=("r"+input('enter file location: '))
```

Even when I copy the file path, that worked for me (both with and without the "r" it doesn't work)

Comment: Please add the error you are getting

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: What particular error is your code "bringing"?  What are you entering in response to `input`?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129556/1643973

Comment: If this is running under Python 2.x, you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: @shaikmoeed : No, you don't want to do this. Why do you want to replace one backslash in the path with two? Do you understand the difference between the content of a string and the representation of a string?

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for pointing. I checked and now I'm clear. It stores by default as `\\ ` no need to do it explicitly with `replace`. Deleted the wrong comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

> This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems

```
from pathlib import Path:
file_path = Path(input('enter file location: '))
```